# Pushing data from a server to Web based UI elements

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, raspberry-pi, push

I want to connect a bunch of weather sensors to a Raspberry PI. Writing the daemon that reads the sensors and writes the data to a database will be the easy part since I'm a systems programmer. I also want a simple cross platform UI for this device so I'd like to set my Raspberry Pi up as a WIFI hotspot that people can connect to and then just entering a URL like 'weather.local' into a browser which would take them to a web page where the weather sensor data is continually updated. I.e. I want the sensor daemon to 'push' updates to the web page.

The problem is that I'm no web developer. The solutions I can think of off the top of my head are:

1. Flash, which is out because I want this to work on mobile browsers.
2. Using Java script and hanging HTTP requests to a web service.
3. HTML5 socket.io which is presumably the same as WebSocket.

If I go with option (2) even if it's a kind of polling, I'll have to incorporate some form of HTTP server into my sensor daemon and I have a fair idea of how to code that. My question, however, regards the HTML5 socket IO. Can I use this to connect directly to a TCP/IP binary socket or do I need a server side WebSocket library? Also how widely is HTML5 socket.io/WebSocket implemented on mobile browsers?

Comment: You might want to go for a solution that takes care of the complexity of choosing the best transport for each client. Take a look at the demos on www.lightstreamer.com (full disclosure: I am the co-founder of Lightstreamer)

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket always begins with an [upgrade handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.2) over HTTP, so you do need to have basic HTTP capability. It's simple enough that you can hand-code it.

WebSockets is basically supported by all modern browsers. It is not used that widely because it's a pain to set up on traditional HTTP servers and messes up with many proxies, but that's not a problem for you. As long as the client is a recent version of anything, it'll work.

A note about option 2: browsers have a [native implementation of it](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#server-sent-events) — that means you don't need so much JavaScript on the client. You just create the EventSource object and listen to its events.

Comment: Thanks dude, that really helped me. Hanging HTTP requests seemed a bit clunky and since I'm used to Berkley sockets went with a WebSockets and it's way more elegant. I knocked up a proof-of-concept app with a C++ process that uses libsockets on the server end and JavaScript+WebSockets for the web front end. I can now update a HTML <label> object in-place with weather data values. It's surprisingly smooth and snappy over a local area network and the web page can easily handle a weather data update every second or so. It even works perfectly on iOS and Android.